# How to solve json dictionary?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, xcode, uitableview

How to solve this JSON array i'm trying to many times but can't fetch "business_details" array. I fetch only first "business_category_name"
then "business_details" array do not fetch.
I think not explain properly please try to understand and please help me.
I am very tired

## Json

```
 "status": [
{
  "business_category_name": "Banks\/Credit Unions\/Landers",
  "business_details": [
    {
      "img_url": "http:\/\/edutimeapp.com\/toshow\/chamber-of-commerc\/member-logo\/1464667619-pnc.jpg",
      "name": "PNC Bank",
      "des": "PNC offers a wide range of services for all our customers, from individuals and small businesses, to corporations and government entities",
      "address": "",
      "email": "andrea.kendall@pnc.com",
      "phone": "260-422-5922",
      "member_since": "2016-05-31",
      "img_company": "http:\/\/edutimeapp.com\/toshow\/chamber-of-commerc\/member-logo\/1464667619-pnc.jpg",
      "website": "",
      "city": "Fort Wayne",
      "state": "IN",
      "zip": "46808"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "business_category_name": "Cleaning Services",
  "business_details": [
    {
      "img_url": "http:\/\/edutimeapp.com\/toshow\/chamber-of-commerc\/uploads\/logo250.png",
      "name": "tsst company",
      "des": "rudurgg ",
      "address": "2005 s calhoun ",
      "email": "",
      "phone": "2602496687",
      "member_since": "2016-05-31",
      "img_company": "http:\/\/edutimeapp.com\/toshow\/chamber-of-commerc\/uploads\/logo250.png",
      "website": "",
      "city": "fort wayne",
      "state": "in",
      "zip": "46825"
    }
  ]
},
```

## Use Json data

```
 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{

 NSError *error;


NSLog(@"Error in receiving data %@",error);

NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&error];

 NSLog(@"response data %@",json);


NSArray *results = [json objectForKey:@"status"];

 namearray= [results valueForKey:@"business_category_name"];

 emailarray = [results valueForKey:@"email"];

 [self.tableview reloadData];

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ViewController.m**

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
     NSArray * yourArray;
}


NSLog(@"response data %@",json);
NSArray *results = [json objectForKey:@"status"];    
yourArray = [[[results objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"business_details"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

This will give you output of "business_details" for 0 index(first object)

**Output :**

```
[
    {
      "img_url": "http:\/\/edutimeapp.com\/toshow\/chamber-of-commerc\/member-logo\/1464667619-pnc.jpg",
      "name": "PNC Bank",
      "des": "PNC offers a wide range of services for all our customers, from individuals and small businesses, to corporations and government entities",
      "address": "",
      "email": "andrea.kendall@pnc.com",
      "phone": "260-422-5922",
      "member_since": "2016-05-31",
      "img_company": "http:\/\/edutimeapp.com\/toshow\/chamber-of-commerc\/member-logo\/1464667619-pnc.jpg",
      "website": "",
      "city": "Fort Wayne",
      "state": "IN",
      "zip": "46808"
    }
]
```

If you want to use it within your `tableview` then you need to write `indexPath.row` in place of index as below.

```
yourArray = [[[results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"business_details"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I used  tableview indexPath.row  same as but results array undeclared identifier  error. how to use please explain

Comment: I used my array but results undeclared identifier error show. please help me i'm very tired.

Comment: I can't help you without checking your project! Because now I am also not getting why such error.

Comment: How to send my project please send your email id.  please do not ignore. thanks

Comment: Share your project with dropbox link or upload your project on ge.tt and share me the link

Comment: Hey! What do you want to display in title label?

Comment: Download your project with resolved error from this link, http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00225482663861337181
 It's working fine.

Comment: Thanks for replay, and thank you thank you sooooo much dear sir. working is very fine. :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If the complete output is a dictionary referred by `json`, you can do that:

```
NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response 
                                                            options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                                              error:&error];
NSArray *status = json[@"status"];
NSDictionary *firstStatus = status[0];
NSArray *businessDatails = firstStatus[@"business_details"]
// Likely you want to continue
NSDictionary *firstBusinessDetail = businessDetails[0];
NSMutableString *name = firstBusinessDetail[@"name"]M
```

or put it all together:

```
NSMutableArray *businessDatails = json[@"status"][0][@"business_details"];
```

Comment: *UITableViewCell indexing in a do not load* What does that mean?

Comment: *simple label on a print string but TableView Cell label in a not print name string.* And this?

Comment: thanks for reply, solve my problem. thanks for To give your precious time. :)